# TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
table_1
-------------
| id | status|
-------------
| 1  | no |
-------------
| 2  | no |
-------------
| 3  | no |
-------------
| 4  | no |
-------------
| 5  | no |
-------------


table_2
------------------------
| id | a1 | b2 |  ridx  |
------------------------
| 1  | 5  | 0  | 1,2,3 |
------------------------
| 2  | 3  | 0  | 4,5 |
------------------------
```

I am trying to create a trigger that will:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test1 AFTER UPDATE ON table_2
FOR EACH ROW
IF OLD.a1 = NEW.b2 THEN
UPDATE table_1 SET status = "OK" WHERE id IN (OLD.ridx);
END IF
```

my trigger only update 1 id to status OK in table_1

how to update table_1 all status to OK from id in rows ridx

Comment: change `WHERE id IN (OLD.ridx);` to `where find_in_set(id,OLD.ridx) > 0 `

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty: Much better! Thank you!!!